# What is the use case for a Android Future?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

For context, I am an Android developer who is familiar with using AsyncTask's but has recently started working on a project which is heavily using Future's. The Futures do not have a callback and require checks on `isDone()` to determine progress.

I am having trouble understanding what the purpose and use case of Future is in Android. AsyncTask's provide what seems like the same functionality but with in my opinion a better interface which has callbacks built in that enable the client to clearly determine when the async operation is complete without having to constantly check `isDone()`.

What is the use and purpose of a Future in Android, and why would I use Future or FutureTask over an AsyncTask?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`Future`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html) is part of the Java API, whereas the [`AsyncTask`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) is Android specific. In fact, if you take a look at the [source code of `AsyncTask`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.0.2_r1/android/os/AsyncTask.java/), you will see that it actually uses a `FutureTask` for its implementation:

```
/**
 * Creates a new asynchronous task. This constructor must be invoked on the UI thread.
 */
public AsyncTask() {
    mWorker = new WorkerRunnable<Params, Result>() {
        public Result call() throws Exception {
            mTaskInvoked.set(true);

            Process.setThreadPriority(Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND);
            //noinspection unchecked
            return postResult(doInBackground(mParams));
        }
    };

    mFuture = new FutureTask<Result>(mWorker) {
        @Override
        protected void done() {
            try {
                postResultIfNotInvoked(get());
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                android.util.Log.w(LOG_TAG, e);
            } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException("An error occured while executing doInBackground()",
                        e.getCause());
            } catch (CancellationException e) {
                postResultIfNotInvoked(null);
            }
        }
    };
}
```

The `AsyncTask` is thus just a helper class for short threading jobs, which also handles some [thread pooling](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#executeOnExecutor(java.util.concurrent.Executor,%20Params...)). My guess is that the original writers of your project were familiar with `Future`s, but not with `AsyncTask`, or generally disliked `AsyncTask`.

---

Since I dislike the original `AsyncTask` implementation due to its `Exception` handling, I went on a search for a better alternative, and found [RoboGuice's SafeAsyncTask](https://github.com/roboguice/roboguice/blob/master/roboguice/src/main/java/roboguice/util/SafeAsyncTask.java). In this implementation, an `onException(Exception)` callback is available, but `RuntimeException`s get propagated to that callback as well.

I think a `NullPointerException` should make the app just crash, and I modified this `SafeAsyncTask` a little while back to do exactly this. The result can be found [here](https://github.com/Label305/Stan-for-Android/blob/master/lib-async/src/main/java/com/label305/stan/async/AsyncTask.java).

Comment: Thanks, I suspect that either the case you mention or that they were trying to "simulate" synchronous behavior.  It's informative to know that Async is using FutureTask and also I was not aware of the exception handling issues with AsyncTask.